# Why properties of function not overrided to default when new instance of object created?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Please explain why new instance **obj2** of function foo still have element in items array? Why it's not overrided when I call new foo()?

```
var foo = function() {}

foo.prototype = {
    items : [],
  addItem : function()
  {
    this.items.push("item");
  }
}

var obj = new foo();
obj.addItem();

console.log(obj.items.length); //1 as expected

var obj2 = new foo();

console.log(obj2.items.length); // 1, why not 0?????
```

Comment: You've added it to the prototype which means all instances will share it.

Comment: Do you want to override normal function methods for `foo`? If not, I wouldn't override the entire `prototype`.

Answer (score 1):

You've added it to the prototype which means all instances will share it. You want a new `items` array for every instance of `Foo`. To achieve this, you need to move that out of the `prototype` and into the body of your function. You will attach it to `this`.

```
function Foo() {
  this.items = [];
}

Foo.prototype.addItem = function(item) {
  this.items.push(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of your `items` references to 1 array so it will be the same array in all new object (obj1 and obj2).

Your `foo` should be:

```
function foo() {
  this.items = []
  this.addItem = function() { ... }
}
```